# How to create a group with PIM elevation in Azure

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm new to Azure AD. and trying to create access package.

My requirement is to Create a group 1st then elevate that group for PIM, then create access package, and then assign groups to scope.

I'm not sure, if there is any setting that needs to be enabled for PIM elevation during group creation. I searched the web but didn't get appropriate steps.

### Edit

Particularly for assign groups to scope:

I think, this (**assign groups to scope**) can be done from the subscription -> Access control(IAM) -> "Role assignment" ; where my scope is showing  "this resource" where as it should be a **resource group name**. Anything I am missing here?

Comment: Hello @AskMe, Which you have edited it is for assign scope to Azure Resources not for the Azure AD groups.

Comment: Hi @RahulKumarShaw-MT - If my edit is  "assign scope to Azure Resources" - What is the correct steps to do it? I gauss, I have very less knowledge. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @AskMe added answer for your edit.

Answer (score 1):

For elevate that group for PIM and create access package You should have **Azure AD Premium P2 license**

Please refer this Microsoft Document for [PIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-configure#license-requirements) and [Access Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-group-licenses?wt.mc_id=azureportal_gettingstarted_inproduct_idgovernance).

Once you have above licence you can follow this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/groups-discover-groups) for PIM of a Group

Edit--

> I think, this(assign groups to scope) can be done from the
> subscription -> Access control(IAM) -> "Role assignment" ; where my
> scope is showing "this resource" where as it should be a resource
> group name. - Anything Am I missing here?

If you are assiging the group to a scope on subscription level then if you go IAM ->Role Assigment it will show you This Resouce only and if you to your resource it will show subscription[inherited].

Likewise if you are assigning a scope to resource group level then if you go to resourcegroup-> role assigment it will show this resource and if you check inside the resources present in your resource group it will be resource group[Inherited].

Comment: Hi @Rahul  - Thanks for the details. After access package creation, any documentation on  "Assign groups to Scope" ? Where I have 'catalog' , 'access package' , 'scope' , 'role' , 'Group'

Comment: @AskMe, for assigning scope to Azure AD group you can follow this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/groups-assign-role

Comment: There is a edit in my question - I think, that is one way. However, I will check the above link.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's done.

Go to "Group" and search for "assignment group" that is created. Let's say "xxx_contributor" -> select and click on that -> then click on "Privileged access (Preview) [from left blade] -> Click on "Enable privilege access" -> click on "add assignment" -> select "role" as "member" -> click on "select member" -> search for the member, let's say "xxx_contributor_eligible" -> click " next" and click "assign".